# Difference in the payload for CANCEL notification for Upgrade and Customer support cancellation for Apple subscription notification

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewable

Apple sends Server to Server notifications for Subscription related changes of a customer. `CANCEL` notification is sent out in two scenarios:

1. User calls customer care to cancel their subscription.
2. User changes to an upgraded plan.

In case 2, an `INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL` notification is followed by `CANCEL`.

When the CANCEL notification is received, we may not have any way to determine if it is for case 1 or 2.

Is there a difference in the payload fields' values for CANCEL notification been triggered for the two cases.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

In the `latest_receipt_info` JSON there is a `product_id` field and an `auto_renew_product_id` field. If they are different then that indicates the user is changing products.

Comment: latest_receipt_info is an array of subscriptions. how to select canceled subscription.?